# onclick event shows wrong element

Tags: javascript, onclick

I need some help with my code:

```
var p = document.getElementById("place-users");

class User {

constructor(name, age, job) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.job = job;
}

createUser(){
this.name = prompt("Wat is uw naam");
this.age = prompt("Wat is uw leeftijd");
this.job = prompt("Wat is uw beroep");
}

placeUsers() {
    p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = this.name + " " + this.age + " " + this.job;
    document.getElementById("place-users").append(p);
 }
 }

let user = new User("User ", "1 ", "AI");

var showInfo = p.onclick = function() {
alert("Hallo " + user.name)
}
```

when the alert comes it will always shows the latest user created even when i click on a different user?

does someone know what i do wrong?

Comment: show more code... for the moment we only see just only one " user " and no more...